# How to change @html object attributes based on value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Edit View in MVC5 / C#.  Within that view, there is an @html.TextBox which contains an integer.  If that integer is less than zero, I would like to change the Textbox to bold and red.  And change some other html object (attributes) - like a drop down box to be locked.

I have looked at some stuff with JScript but it is very new to me.  And I can't quite get there.  Not even sure if JScript is the right way to go.

Here is my html/view of the TextBox which contains the integer.

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitsOrdered, (string)"Units Remaining ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("Remaining", null, new { @class = "form-control", Value = ViewBag.Total, @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

If "Remaining" is less than zero, I would like the font text in "Remaining" to be red and bold.  I would also like to make the dropdown "CheckOpen" to become Locked or ReadOnly.  (This will prevent users from processing an order when the balance is negative)

I am lost with JScript as to how to control the attributes of the html objects and how to find them by id.

I assume I would need to do this in document.ready . . . as I want this to happen immediately after page loads.

```
            <!-- Begin JScript for negative balance-->
            <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {

             });

            </script>
        <!-- End JScript for Negative Balance-->
```

***With the help from the comments (below), I was able to accomplish what I needed.***

I added some css styles here:

```
<style>
.pos {
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.neg {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

***And this was my final Jscript that worked***

```
            <!-- Begin JScript for negative balance-->
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    var remaining = $('#Remaining').val();


                    if (remaining > -1) {
                        $("#Remaining").addClass("pos");
                        $('select[name=CheckOpen]').prop('disabled', false);

                    } else {
                        $("#Remaining").addClass("neg");

                        $('select[name=CheckOpen]').prop('disabled', true);

                    }                                   
             });

            </script>
        <!-- End JScript for Negative Balance-->
```

With this, The text turns red and bold if the int is less than 0, and disables the additional dropdown.  If the int is 0 or greater, the text remains black, and the additional dropdown remains enabled.

Thank you!!!

Comment: @Html.TextBox("Remaining" ../ creates an element with ID="Remaining" var remaining = $('#Remaining').val(); will return the value for the textbox. $('#Remaining').addClass('myStyle') to change to bold red text. $('#Remaining').removeClass('myStyle') to remove bold red styling. Please attempt to solve with this info and update your question.

Comment: Another clue... $('#Remaining').on('change', function() { // change style here });

Comment: Note that JScript is a now-defunct implementation of JavaScript. You're better off just calling in JavaScript or ECMAScript these days. Also, you may want to look into the validation framework so that you don't have to roll your own: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: With the hints that @daddygames provided, and some more google searching, I was able to get it working.  Thank you!  I will update the question above so that anyone looking to do similar, can find the answer.